# Rails scope with Arel, NOW() return to me NULL after migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've migrated my app to Rails 6.0

I have this scope

```
  scope :published,      -> { where(state: 'published').where arel_table[:published_at].lteq 'NOW()' }
```

This is the query generated by activerecord on `Content.published`

```
SELECT "contents".* FROM "contents" WHERE "contents"."state" = $1 AND "contents"."published_at" <= NULL ORDER BY "contents"."published_at" DESC  [["state", "published"]]
=> []
```

Why `NOW()` is `NULL`??

Answer (score 1):

Use a symbol to tell arel that you're not just passing dangerous strings into a query, but have made sure it's safe to print into the query.

```rb
-> { where(state: 'published').where arel_table[:published_at].lteq :'NOW()' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite this query to use a literal string for the WHERE condition:

```rb
scope :published, -> { where(state: 'published').where('published_at <= NOW()');
```

Though, when designing these types of apps, it's more common to leave the date as as NULL for unpublished books, then find records that are published by querying this way:

```rb
scope :published, -> { where(state: 'published').where('published_at IS NOT NULL');
```

(Perhaps yours is already designed like that?)

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: No they are still present 

https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/Core/ClassMethods/arel_table

Comment: You're right - I edited my answer without that first note about arel_table. Hope that helps :)